# Extending Joomla 2.5 Banner Component

Tags: joomla

I really hope someone can help me.

I need to be able to serve banners in categories which are dependant on a session variable - and can't find a component which does that. So I'd like to extend the Joomla Banner component in order to select banners based on a session variable which contains the category path.

The correct session variable is being stored correctly.

In order to do this I added an option in the banners module `.xml` to allow for a session variable and the name of the session variable. This is being stored correctly in the module table within the `params` field along with the other module parameters.

Then I started on the

> components > banners > com_banners > models > banners.php

by adding two lines of code in `getListQuery` where the `SQL` is assembled. They are:

```
$sess_vars  = $this->getState('filter.sess_vars');
$sess_vars_name = $this->getState('filter.sess_vars_name');
```

But both variables contain nothing even though the ones the component already has can be retrieved fine. Without a doubt I need to change something somewhere else as well - but just can't figure out what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add what code you used to store the session variable?

Answer (score 1):

1. The first thing to do is **not hack the core files**, hacking the core prevents you from using the built-in update feature to apply the regular bug fixes and security patches released by Joomla! (e.g. *the [recently released 2.5.9 version](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5477-joomla-2-5-9-released.html)*).
2. Rather make a copy of them and modify it so it's called something else like `com_mybanners`. Apart from the folder name and the entry point file (i.e. `banners.php` becomes `mybanners.php`) you will also want to update the components `banners.xml` to `mybanners.php`.
   (*You will need to duplicate and modify both the front end `/components/com_banners/` and `/administrator/components/mybanners.php`.*)
3. Because of the way Banners work (i.e. banners are displayed in a module) you will also need to duplicate and modify `/modules/mod_banners/`,`/modules/mod_banners/mod_banners.php` and `/modules/mod_banners/mod_banners.xml`. Changing `mod_banners` to `mod_mybanners` in each location.
4. In Joomla! components the `state` is usually populated when JModel is instantiated, however, in this case the component is really about managing banners and recording clicks the display is handled by `mod_banners`. So, you will want to add some code to `mod_mybanners.php` to use the session variables you want to act on.
    Normally when a models state is queried you will collect the variables via [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) and add them to your object's state e.g.

```php
protected function populateState()
{
    $jApp = JFactory::getApplication('site');

    // Load state from the request.
    $pk = $jApp->input->get('id',0,'INT');
    $this->setState('myItem.id', $pk);

    $offset = $jApp->input->get('limitstart',0,'INT');
    $this->setState('list.offset', $offset);

    // Load the parameters.
    $params = $app->getParams();
    $this->setState('params', $params);

    // Get the user permissions
    $user       = JFactory::getUser();
    if ((!$user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_mycomponent')) &&  (!$user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_mycomponent')))
    {
        $this->setState('filter.published', 1);
        $this->setState('filter.archived', 2);
    }
}
```

The `populateState()` method is called when a state is read by the `getState` method.

This means you will have to change your copy of `/components/com_banners/models/banner.php` to capture your variables into the objects state similar to my example above.

From there it's all your own code.

You can find all of this information in the [Developing a Model-View-Controller tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5) on the [Joomla Doc's site](http://docs.joomla.org/)

Comment: you're welcome — it's a good idea to mark an answer as "Accepted" if it solves your problem or to upvote it if it helps (or even both it the answer merits it).